# fractional integral with integral measure on a fractional power

Tags: calculus, integration, fractional-calculus

I got a bit familiar with fractional calculus, and it seems that the Riemann-Liouville differintegral formula (and all other similar formulas) are defined for a function $f$ that is one dimensional, and they mean a repeated amount of integration/differentiation with fractional power. So if there is an operator $D$ that performs the integration/differentiation $n$ times, then one should apply $D(D(D(\dots D(f))))$, $n$ times. The full theory extends this $n$ to non-integer numbers.

My question is not exactly related to this, but rather I'm looking for a definition of a fractional integral where the power $a$ of the integration defines the "dimensionality" of the problem, e.g. $a = 2$ would mean a $2$-dimensional integral instead of integrating twice.

I would be interested if there is any definition of $\int dx^{\alpha} f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is not strictly a one-dimensional function, but it can be "arbitrary", or not even a function but some other "function-placeholder" (to call it like that).

Comment: I am not sure to well understand your question. Supposing thant you mean the fractional integration of degree $\alpha$ then use the definition of fractional derivative of degree $-\alpha$. An article for the general public: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire , page 9 English translation (not scientific article).

Comment: In every source I read, f is R -> R , and as an example the fractional integration for integer value 2 integrates it twice. My question is if it is also defined for R^2 functions ? So I am looking for some definition of dx^a where if a is 1 then it integrates along a line, if 2 then on a surface..and fractional powers are fractional measures. The Caputo and Riemann-Liouville are not doing that.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean, because maybe the question would be a little clearer?

Comment: Let me extend the question then!

Comment: I think I now understand what you are looking for. I've never heard of anything like this before. What comes closest is probably the marichev-saigo-maeda generalized fractional operator and the fractional multivariable H-function. I hope this might help you, although I doubt it.